# How to get current month in codeigniter (translation)

Tags: php, codeigniter, date-format, lang

I've just install translation to codeigniter.

At the beginning of my controller I've set:

```
public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('MyVeryFirst_model');
   $this->lang->load('calendar', 'polish');
   $this->load->helper('date');
}
```

Next in function

```
echo mdate(%F);
```

it shows me month in English, why?

```
echo $this->lang->line('cal_december');
echo timespan('1079621429', time());
```

Shows me names in polish which is ok. I've set locale to polish.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Note: The text generated by this function (**timespan()**) is found in the following language file: language//date_lang.php Check you date_lang.php in polish directory and look if everything is translated to polish.

Comment: Yes it's translated to polish. Also calendar_lang which contains tranlated names of months is also translated

Comment: mdate(%F); should produce something like this: 2012-12-10

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_(Unix) ah the link is screwed try this http://bit.ly/T2KCz  Search for "%F". Try die(); your code and find out which line is causing your problem. You have probably some mistake in your code.

Comment: OK, but i just want current month in my language, do I realy need to check all code? I doubt that i've done some mistakes. I've just have only few line of code and it's 100% ok :(

Comment: Try %B instead of %F. If it is not working post the whole code of your controller and view on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why it won't work, so I used some little trick

```
$vars['today'] = date("d ").$this->lang->line("cal_".strtolower(date("F"))).date(" Y");
```